# How to Reference a Value on Index Page Using a Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-core, foreign-keys, razor-pages

In my Officer model, I have a foreign key that references what agency an officer belongs to. I need this so that users can assign an officer to an agency on my Officers Create page.

However, on my Officers Index page, I would like to show the text value (AgencyName from the Agency model) of what that foreign key refers to rather than the foreign key itself, as that will be much more meaningful to users (although showing BOTH the key and Value is fine).

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DWITracker.Model
{
    public class Officer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Officer Name (Last, First, MI)")]
        public string? OfficerDisplayName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string? OfficerFirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "MI")]
        public string? OfficerMiddleInitial { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string? OfficerLastName { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Agency")]
        public int AgencyId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Agency ID")]
        public Agency? Agency { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DWITracker.Model
{
    public class Agency
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Agency")]
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The portion of my Index page where I would like to have the proper AgencyName display:

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var obj in Model?.Officer)
            {
            <tr>
                <td width="30%">@obj.OfficerDisplayName</td>
                <td width="10%">@obj.AgencyId</td>
                <td width="30%">@obj.Agency?.AgencyName</td>
                <td width="15%">@obj.UpdatedBy</td>
                <td width="15%">@obj.UpdateDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                        <a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">
                            <i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
using DWITracker.Data;
using DWITracker.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DWITracker.Pages.Officers;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Officer> Officer { get; set; }

    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    [BindProperty]
    public List<Officer>? OfficersList { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _db = db;
    }

    public string OfficerSort { get; set; }
    public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string searchString, List<Officer>OfficersList)
    {

        this.OfficersList = await _db.Officer.Include(x => x.Agency).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

        OfficerSort = sortOrder == "Officer_Asc_Sort" ? "Officer_Desc_Sort" : "Officer_Asc_Sort";
        CurrentFilter = searchString;

        IQueryable<Model.Officer> findOfficer = from s in _db.Officer select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
           findOfficer = findOfficer.Where(s => s.OfficerDisplayName.Contains(searchString));

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Officer_Asc_Sort":
                findOfficer = findOfficer.OrderBy(s => s.OfficerDisplayName);
                break;
            case "Officer_Desc_Sort":
                findOfficer = findOfficer.OrderByDescending(s => s.OfficerDisplayName);
                break;
            default:
                findOfficer = findOfficer.OrderBy(s => s.OfficerDisplayName);
                break;
        }
        OfficersList = await findOfficer.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]. [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
 [ask] [Help] PS Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) related with Read related data

and here's a minimal example for you :

PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly RazorPageApplication1Context _context;

        [BindProperty]
        public List<Officer> Officers { get; set; }=new List<Officer>();

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, RazorPageApplication1Context context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            this.Officers= _context.Officer.Include(x=>x.Agency).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Razor:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
            @foreach(var obj in Model.Officers)
            {
            <tr>
                <td width="40%">@obj.OfficerDisplayName</td>
                <td width="40%">@obj.Agency.AgencyName</td>
                <td width="20%">
                    <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                        <a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-primary mx-2">
                            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square">Edit</i>
                        </a>
                        <a asp-page="Delete" asp-route-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">
                            <i class="bi bi-trash-fill">Delete</i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
      </tbody>
</table>
```

DB:

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your demo code. I have attempted to work it into my existing .cs, but am receiving an error when running the program on the Index.cshtml page at <td width="40%">@obj.Agency.AgencyName</td>. It has the error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' It also tells me that the _logger is never being read. Ideas on what I have wrong?

Comment: Since you get the NullReferenceException,have you checked if the Agency property of the instance of Officer is null? try and a judgement,if ( @obj.Agency!=null)...

Comment: beacuse you setted :Agency?   it means Agency could be null , if Agency is null,when you read Agency.AgencyName ,you would get a NullReferenceException

Comment: If you still have problems ,i'll reply you tomorrow

Comment: Added ? here: <td width="30%">@obj.Agency?.AgencyName</td> and was able to eliminate the null error, but I get nothing in the Agency Name column on my Index view and there should be an Agency Name there. Not sure why? My Agency model does have data in it.

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Your comment is contradicted by the links I gave & by the text content of the images. I'm done.

Comment: Have you checked the document about read related data with EFCore I provied at the begining?

Comment: Yes. As I have said, I have read, but do not understand well enough to know what the issue is. I am thinking it could be my public async Task OnGetAsync but not sure.

Comment: I have finally figured it out. In the Index.cshtml,, the model should NOT be Officer, but rather OfficersList. Once I changed it to be like this: <table>
    <tbody>
            @foreach(var obj in Model.OfficersList)
            {           it worked just fine!!!

Comment: My only issue now is that my search and sort do not work. I'm getting a message that OfficerDisplayName may be null here. Thinking I need to refer to the OfficersList once again instead of the Officer Model, but am not sure of the correct syntax to do that. can anyone assist please?

Comment: Check this document related with null reference types:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types